# Fairness of 'answer ordering'

Tags: feature-request, answers, answer-order

Partly a loaded question, but take as an example: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268411/assigning-code-commits-master-version-numbers/3268447#3268447)

I was the second to answer here, yet appear last on the list. There is an identical answer to mine posted that appears above mine, that wasn't there until after mine. In my opinion, the top most upvoted answer isn't the correct one, but is upvoted (in my opinion) due the rep count.

The system seems broken. Is there a way to fix it; a way to make it fairer for the people taking time to answer the questions?

Comment: Pro tip: sort by date!

Comment: You're describing the [Fastest Gun in the West](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) problem, which is supposed to be partially mitigated by randomizing the order of equally-ranked answers (as waiwai933 said)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answers with the same score are sorted randomly for each page load, assuming that you have the `votes` tab selected. If the answer currently with +1 is incorrect, I suggest you leave a comment on it explaining why it is wrong and then downvote it.